# Controling and getting data from clients of applications by node.js

Tags: node.js, computer-vision, controls, bots

I want to try create simple bot for game(game has own client), which will be control character(may be mouse move and keys press) and read information from screen. Advice please ways/packets for node.js.
Any information will be useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`robotjs`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/robotjs) is a npm module that provides all of the functionality you described in the question. The documentation on its website goes over individual walkthroughs on how to handle mouse, keyboard, and screen reading functionality.

Comment: what about convert image to text?